# django-pytest setup_method database issue

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-django

I have the following set up on Ubuntu 14.04:

- python 2.7.6
- django 1.7 [though I reproduced the same behaviour with
  django 1.9 too]
- pytest-django 2.8.0 [also tested with 2.9.1]
- pytest 2.7.2 [also tested with 2.8.3]

And the following test code:

```
import pytest
from django.db import connection

import settings
from pollsapp.models import Question

original_db_name = settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"]

@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestExperiment(object):

    def setup_method(self, method):
        # it's not using the "test_" + DATABASE_NAME !
        assert connection.settings_dict["NAME"] == \ 
        settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"]
        Question.objects.create(question_text="How are you?")
        # this data remains in the main database
```

1. Although the class is marked to use django database, the data created in the constructor arrive in the main (production) database (name taken from settings.py)
2. Putting the `django_db` decorator above the `setup_method` does not make any difference
3. This data created in the setup_method remain in the main database, are not rolled back as they should be and as they would be if the data creation call was made in the `test_case` method
4. This behaviour happens when the test is run on its own. When running it within the test suite, the setup_method db calls fails with: Failed: Database access not allowed, use the `django_db` mark to enable
   although the decorator is clearly there (which means that this error message is not to be 100% trusted btw).

pytest is an awesome framework and django-pytest works great if database calls happen from `django_db` marked test case methods.

It looks like no db interaction should ever be present in special pytest methods such as `setup_method`, `teardown_method`, etc. Although the documentation doesn't say anything about it:

https://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/database.html

I am getting this behaviour with both Django 1.7 as well as with 1.9 (latest stable).

Here is the link to the whole test module: https://github.com/zdenekmaxa/examples/blob/master/python/django-testing/tests/pytest_djangodb_only.py

Comment: decorator should be on method, not on class.

Comment: If it is, the doesn't make any difference. And according to the django-pytest documentation, module, class, method or function level are all possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, setup_X methods does not play nice with pytest fixtures. pytest-django's database setup is based on pytest fixtures, and therefore it does not work.

I recommend that you make your setup_method an autouse fixture, that requests the db fixture:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestExperiment(object):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup_stuff(self, db):
        Question.objects.create(question_text="How are you?")

    def test_something(self):
        assert Question.objects.filter(question_text="How are you?").exists()
```

The error message given by pytest-django is confusing and misleading, I've opened an issue to track/fix this: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/297

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, this works on setup_method as intended but still getting Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark to enable in the same way marked `def teardown_method(self, db):` Thanks for your explanation, I assumed to refrain from db interactions in the pytest's special methods.

Comment: setup_X and teardown_X may break at any time. You should use fixtures for all test setting up and tearing down. https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code describes how you can register a function to run during teardown. It will have proper database access. Please mark the answer as accepted if you're happy with it.